# cannot change integer variable from nested function

Tags: python-3.x

As we know nested functions can access the outer function variables like the below code.

```
def a():
    i=[2]
    
    def b():
        i.append(1)
        print(i)
    b()
a() #output: [2,1]
```

However, for the below code I am getting error

```
def a():
    i=0
    
    def b():
        i=i+1
        print(i)
    b()
a() ###UnboundLocalError: local variable 'i' referenced before assignment
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue appears on the second `i` from `i=i+1`. With the first `i` you are shadowing the outer scope variable with a local `i` and then attempt to use it before it was initialized. To solve this you can use the `nonlocal` keyword:

```
def a():
    i = 0

    def b():
        nonlocal i
        i = i + 1
        print(i)

    b()


a()  # outputs 1
```